# Although the identity is authenticated, it does not navigate to the requested page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

After pressing the login button and authenticating, I want the application to direct me to the desired page. But either it does not redirect when I press the button, or even if I enter the wrong password, it goes to the desired page and comes back. because it hasn't been authenticated yet. I couldn't find the right way.

When authenticated, I want to go to the page with the resource list. The path of this page is "/".

I'm sharing a few pieces of code to give you an idea.
App:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="link">
      <MiniDrawer>
        <Outlet />
      </MiniDrawer>
    </div>
  );
};

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },

  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <AdminGuard>
        <Layout />
      </AdminGuard>
    ),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Resources />,
      },
      {
        path: "/create",
        element: <CreateResource />,
      },
      {
        path: "/edit/:id",
        element: <EditResource />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function App({ Component }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Guard:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.services";

const AdminGuard = ({ children }) => {
  if (AuthService.isAuthenticated()) {
    return children;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }
};

export default AdminGuard;
```

Login Page:

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import LoginView from "./view";
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.services";

function Login() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  function onSubmit({ username, password }) {
    dispatch(AuthService.userLogin({ username, password }));
  }

  return (
    <>
      <LoginView onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Auth Service:

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { axiosApiInstance } from "./axios.services";
import { TokenService } from "./token.service";

export const AuthService = {};
AuthService.userLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "userSlice/userLogin",
  async ({ username, password }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await axiosApiInstance.post(
        "https://localhost:7105/api/Connect",
        { username, password },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: typeof username === "string" ? username.toString() : "",
            password: typeof password === "string" ? password.toString() : "",
          }),
        }
      );

      const tokenResponse = { accessToken: response?.data };
      TokenService.setToken(tokenResponse);

      return tokenResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);

AuthService.isAuthenticated = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem("access_token") ? true : false;
};
AuthService.logout = () => {
  TokenService.clearToken();
  window.location.href = "/login";
};
```

Token Service:

```
export const TokenService = {};

TokenService.setToken = ({ accessToken }) => {
  localStorage.setItem("access_token", accessToken);
};

TokenService.clearToken = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
};
```

Auth Slice:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.services";
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  data: {},
  isLoading: false,
  hasError: false,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(AuthService.userLogin.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.hasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(AuthService.userLogin.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
        state.pending = false;
        state.data = payload;
      })
      .addCase(AuthService.userLogin.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.hasError = true;
      });
  },
});

export const selectAuthState = (state) => state.authSlice.data;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything that redirects a user after they authenticate. If I am understanding the issue correctly you need to update the code to handle redirecting to the protected route after they successfully authenticate.

For this I suggest a few changes.

Update the auth check to be stateful instead of relying on reading from localStorage. Updates to localStorage don't trigger React components to rerender so auth checks in the `AdminGuard` are likely to be stale. Since the `state.authSlice.data` state is the token value the UI should reference this value, or specifically `state.authSlice.data.accessToken`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectAuthState } from "../slices/auth.slice";

const AdminGuard = () => {
  // Capture the current location for auth redirect
  const location = useLocation();

  // Access authentication state
  const { accessToken } = useSelector(selectAuthState);

  // Wait until any initial/pending auth checks complete
  if (accessToken === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  // Return Outlet for nested routes if authenticated
  // Return redirect with current location in state
  return accessToken
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" redirect state={{ from: location }} />;
};

export default AdminGuard;
```

Auth service

Update the logout function to also be a thunk. This is so you can add reducer cases to handle resetting/clearing the `state.data` value when a user logs out.

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { axiosApiInstance } from "./axios.services";
import { TokenService } from "./token.service";

export const AuthService = {};

AuthService.userLogin = createAsyncThunk(
  "userSlice/userLogin",
  async ({ username, password }, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axiosApiInstance.post(
        "https://localhost:7105/api/Connect",
        { username, password },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            username: typeof username === "string" ? username.toString() : "",
            password: typeof password === "string" ? password.toString() : "",
          }),
        }
      );

      const tokenResponse = { accessToken: data };
      TokenService.setToken(tokenResponse);

      return tokenResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);

AuthService.userLogout = createAsyncThunk(
  "userSlice/userLogin",
  () => {
    TokenService.clearToken();
  }
);
```

```js
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(AuthService.userLogin.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.hasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(AuthService.userLogin.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.pending = false;
        state.data = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(AuthService.userLogin.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.hasError = true;
      })
      .addCase(AuthService.userLogout.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.hasError = false;
      })
      .addCase(AuthService.userLogout.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.pending = false;
        state.data = {}; // <-- reset on logout
      })
      .addCase(AuthService.userLogout.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.hasError = true;
      });
  },
});
```

App

Update `App` to render the `AdminGuard` as a layout route component.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      {
        element: <AdminGuard />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "/",
            element: <Resources />,
          },
          {
            path: "/create",
            element: <CreateResource />,
          },
          {
            path: "/edit/:id",
            element: <EditResource />,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function App({ Component }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Login

Update the `Login` component's submit handler to wait for the login action to resolve and *then* issue an imperative redirect ***back*** to the route path the user was originally attempting to access.

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import LoginView from "./view";
import { AuthService } from "../../services/auth.services";

function Login() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  onSubmit = async ({ username, password }) => {
    try {
      // Wait for login action to complete, e.g. resolve
      await dispatch(AuthService.userLogin({ username, password })).unwrap();

      // Redirect to original target, or safe non-protected route
      const { from } = state || { from: /* safe fallback that isn't a protected route */ };
      navigate(from, { replace: true });
    } catch(error) {
      // handle errors?
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <LoginView onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    </>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Similarly now the "logout" function is the same, dispatch the `AuthService.userLogout` action and redirect after.

```js
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const navigate = useNavigate();

const logout = async () => {
  try {
    await dispatch(AuthService.userLogout()).unwrap();
    navigate("/login", { replace: true });
  } catch(error) {
    // handle errors?
  }
};
```